# plot for complex equation: why is Mathematica plot different from Maple plot?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, complex

I have a complex equation:

$2 * B * m + 2 * c * v + 2 * M^2 * v - 4 * M5^2 * v - 4 * k1 * v^3 - 4 * k2 * v^3 = 0 $

where $B, m, c, v, M, M5, k1, k2 $ are real variables.

I want to solve it for variable $v$:

```
Solve[2 B m + 2 c v + 2 M^2 v - 4 M5^2 v - 4 k1 v^3 - 4 k2 v^3 == 0, v]
```

An answer is complex:

```
{{v -> (1.63607*10^-14 (-1.33546*10^31 + 
   5.89443*10^26 M5^2))/(-6.05149*10^46 + Sqrt[
  3.66205*10^93 + 4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(
1/3) - 1.03066*10^-14 (-6.05149*10^46 + Sqrt[
   3.66205*10^93 + 4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(
 1/3)}, {v -> -(((8.18035*10^-15 + 
    1.41688*10^-14 I) (-1.33546*10^31 + 
    5.89443*10^26 M5^2))/(-6.05149*10^46 + Sqrt[
   3.66205*10^93 + 4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(
 1/3)) + (5.1533*10^-15 - 8.92577*10^-15 I) (-6.05149*10^46 + 
   Sqrt[3.66205*10^93 + 
    4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(
 1/3)}, {v -> -(((8.18035*10^-15 - 
    1.41688*10^-14 I) (-1.33546*10^31 + 
    5.89443*10^26 M5^2))/(-6.05149*10^46 + Sqrt[
   3.66205*10^93 + 4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(
 1/3)) + (5.1533*10^-15 + 8.92577*10^-15 I) (-6.05149*10^46 + 
   Sqrt[3.66205*10^93 + 
    4. (-1.33546*10^31 + 5.89443*10^26 M5^2)^3])^(1/3)}}
```

I know the approximate values of the parameters:

```
k1 = 16.485010961790245`; k2 = -13.131344420001051`; c = -44687.3983417778; B = 161593.81818181818`; m = 5.5; M = 300;
```

And consequently I may plot real part of it:

```
Plot[{Re[(1.636069372813509`*^-14 (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
         5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2))/(-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
          4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
             5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(1/3) - 
    1.0306591209480217`*^-14 (-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
          4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
             5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(1/3)], 
  Re[-(((8.180346864067545`*^-15 + 
           1.4168776392101725`*^-14 I) (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
           5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2))/(-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
            4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
               5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(
       1/3)) + (5.1532956047401085`*^-15 - 
       8.92576981383125`*^-15 I) (-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
          4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
             5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(1/3)], 
  Re[-(((8.180346864067545`*^-15 - 
           1.4168776392101725`*^-14 I) (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 

           5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2))/(-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
            4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
               5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(
       1/3)) + (5.1532956047401085`*^-15 + 
       8.92576981383125`*^-15 I) (-6.051491252967043`*^46 + \
\[Sqrt](3.662054638473664`*^93 + 
          4.` (-1.3354606752754323`*^31 + 
             5.894433894342971`*^26 M5^2)^3))^(1/3)]}, {M5, 0, 400}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0.461492, 0.563303, 0.0104797], Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.003]}, {RGBColor[
    0.4078757751993936, 0.27540579780035374`, 0.780310562001516], 
    Dashed, Thickness[0.003]}, {RGBColor[0.65, 0., 0.], Dotted, 
    Thickness[0.003]}, {RGBColor[
    0.7055434835026511, 0.5895048315002945, 0.], Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.003]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"first solution", "second solution", "third solution"}, 
   Scaled[{0.8, 0.35}]]]
```

[image]

If I do the same thing in Maple:

```
solve(-4*k1*v^3-4*k2*v^3+4*`(-M5)`^2*v+2*M^2*v+2*C*v+2*b*m = 0, v)
k1 := 16.48501096179024
C := -44687.3983417778
k2 := -13.13134442000105
b := 161593.8181818181
M := 300
m := 5.5
```

Stackexchange has a limit for symbols, but in the construction of plot below I will show explicit form solutions from Maple:

```
plot([6.498027517*10^(-16)*(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)-1.538928540*10^15*(0.9939370219e-1*M5^2-2251.893618)/(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3), -3.249013759*10^(-16)*(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)+7.694642700*10^14*(0.9939370219e-1*M5^2-2251.893618)/(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)+(.8660254038*I)*(6.498027517*10^(-16)*(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)+1.538928540*10^15*(0.9939370219e-1*M5^2-2251.893618)/(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)), -3.249013759*10^(-16)*(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)+7.694642700*10^14*(0.9939370219e-1*M5^2-2251.893618)/(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)-(.8660254038*I)*(6.498027517*10^(-16)*(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3)+1.538928540*10^15*(0.9939370219e-1*M5^2-2251.893618)/(2.414698568*10^50+1.301965372*10^28*sqrt(7.694642700*10^31*M5^6-5.229964194*10^36*M5^4+1.184916421*10^41*M5^2-5.508856818*10^44))^(1/3))], M5 = 0 .. 400)
```

I get the next plot:
[image]

You may see two interesting things:

1) Part of plot that is in Mathematica, isn't in Maple.

2) Solves in Mathematica consist of pieces, but in Maple solves are continuous.

I want to understand where is problem and so my question is: **do you know another method for plotting graph for complex equation in Mathematica?**

Comment: What makes us confident that Maple is correct, instead of Mathematica?

Comment: @user6014 I don't know what is correct.

Comment: @Nasser I did it.

Comment: `Solve[2 B m + 2 c v + 2 M^2 v - 4 M5^2 v - 4 k1 v^3 - 4 k2 v^3 == 0, v, Reals]` reproduces the Maple plot, except for the discontinuous branch jumping.  In this case, reordering with `Solve[2 B m + 2 c v + 2 M^2 v - 4 M5^2 v - 4 k1 v^3 - 4 k2 v^3 == 0 /. v -> -v, v, Reals]` and plotting `Re[-v]` gets the Maple plot exactly.  (The full solution set is the one originally produced by *Mathematica*.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I am amazed Mathematica can do something sensible without encountering massive cancellation error due to those awkward exponents. In an example like this I would recommend setting 'Cubics->False' and perhaps also leaving the parameter values unspecified, substituting them after the fact. So something along these lines: `solns = v /. (Solve[
     2 B m + 2 c v + 2 M^2 v - 4 M5^2 v - 4 k1 v^3 - 4 k2 v^3 == 0, v,
      Cubics -> False] /. {k1 -> 16.485010961790245, 
     k2 -> -13.131344420001051, c -> -44687.3983417778, 
     B -> 161593.81818181818, m -> 5.5, M -> 300})`.

Answer (score 4):

First, there are three complex roots, counting multiplicities, for all values of the parameters.  I don't know Maple nor why the command does not produce all of three.  The *Mathematica* command shows all three (albeit for `M5 > 150.2`, the real parts of the complex-conjugate pair coincide).

Second, the discontinuities are `Sign[x] == x / Abs[x] == x / Sqrt[x^2]` type that sometimes arise with fractional powers.  The problem is complicated enough that tracking down exactly whether and how it can be fixed seemed more work than might be worth it for the site.  One way to see the problem with the first solution returned by `Solve[]` is to plot its numerator and denominator:

```
Plot[Flatten[
   Re@Through[{Numerator, 30 Denominator[#] &}@
      Together[v /. sol[[1]]]]] // Evaluate, {M5, 140, 160}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see an absolute value type vee in the denominator where the numerator and denominator both vanish.

An alternative is [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html). However, it sorts the roots and is usually a discontinuous function of the parameters, too.  In this particular case, it can be used if we substitute `v -> -v`:

```
Block[{
  k1 = 16.485010961790245`,
  k2 = -13.131344420001051`,
  c = -44687.3983417778,
  B = 161593.81818181818`,
  m = 5.5,
  M = 300},
 Plot[Re@Table[
   -Root[
       Evaluate[2 B m + 2 c v + 2 M^2 v - 4 M5^2 v - 4 k1 v^3 - 4 k2 v^3 /. v -> -#] &,
       n],
     {n, 3}] // Evaluate,
  {M5, 0, 400}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]